# bash shell $HOME assignment and script execution

Tags: macos, bash, shell, unix, execution

I've just begun learning Unix and have so far encountered two elementary though difficult to resolve problems:

- When I set `HOME=''` in a shell script to a designated directory, the *current* directory no longer seems to be recognized. That is, 'cd ~/' spits out the message: 'no such file or directory' message. Although, curiously enough, if aliases assignments are made within the script, a source call seems to activated them nonetheless. How come?

Ex:

```
$ more .profile
HOME="~/Documents/Basics/Unix/Unix_and_Perl_course"
cd $HOME
[...]
$ source .profile
-bash: cd: ~/Documents/Basics/Unix/Unix_and_Perl_course: No such file or directory
```

- When I created a simple shell script via nano ('hello.sh'), I can't seem to execute it simply by typing 'hello.sh' in the terminal. This issue fails to resolve even after I 'chmod +x' the file. What's the problem?

Ex:

```
$ more hello.sh 
# my first Unix shell script
echo "Hello World"
$ hello.sh
bash: hello.sh: command not found
```

Thanks!

Comment: There are two distinct questions here. It's better to ask them separately. It's also better to give a meaningful title, to make the question(s) more useful for future readers.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Michael! I'll keep them in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also don't want to 'overload' $HOME, the default location for HOME is always your home directory. If you goof with that, lots of things will break.

As far as hello.sh - thats because you don't have '.' in your $PATH. (Which is a good thing)

Try:

```
./hello.sh
```

If it says it can't execute

```
chmod 755 hello.sh
./hello.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

1. ~ = $HOME
2. . (pwd) is not in $PATH